# Prevenir que Live Server do Vscode vá para o topo da página

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Estou com um problema bem chato que acontece as vezes no Vscode. Uso o live server para ver em tempo real as modificações no HTML, porém toda vez que o live server atualiza ou que eu dou um CTRL+S no CSS, ele "scrolla" pro topo da página. E isso é bem chato, porque quando se trata de uma página grande, tenho que ficar descendo a página a cada alteração.

Não queria trocar de editor pelo costume e facilidade de mexer com o Vscode, mas esse problema está bem chato e me atrasando muito.

Comment: Aqui não acontece isso não... Veja se na URL que está no browser não está com alguma ancora, tipo `http://127.0.0.1:5500/#` (não deveria ter esse `#` no final), as vezes pode ser tb `http://127.0.0.1:5500/#idDaAncoraInterna`, isso tb pode scrollar para lugares indesejados, lembre-se de de limpar a URL e testar para ver se resolve

Comment: Pior que não está, a URL tá limpa "http://127.0.0.1:5500/", e eu já testei tanto no Chrome quando no Firefox, até pensei que poderia ser o navegador. :'(